# Using GoGo Protobuf .proto sources in my own Protobufs with Bazel

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I'm trying to use (import) [GoGo Protobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/gogoproto/gogo.proto) in my Protobuf definitions, specifically [`gogoproto/gogo.proto`](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/gogoproto/gogo.proto).

Currently I'm defining it as an `http_archive`, and I'm not sure whether this is being done by [Gazelle](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle), but in one way or another I can see the available targets when I query the dependency:

```
$ bazel query @com_github_gogo_protobuf//gogoproto:all
@com_github_gogo_protobuf//gogoproto:go_default_library_protos
@com_github_gogo_protobuf//gogoproto:go_default_library
@com_github_gogo_protobuf//gogoproto:gogoproto
Loading: 0 packages loaded
```

However, when I inspect deeper with `--output=build`, I only see `go_library` targets. In order for me to use the `gogo.proto` source as an import in my own Protobuf sources, I need the `proto_library` target to be available.

I've tried defining it on my own (both next to my own `proto_library` and as an overlay BUILD file), but to no avail (due to various errors and conflicts).

I'm guessing that the most idiomatic way would be to get Bazel and/or Gazelle to generate `proto_library` targets for GoGo Protobuf, but I have not yet figured out how to do that.

I would greatly appreciate any insight and / or guidance on this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to indicate the full path in your proto file, something like this:

```
import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";
```